# How to wildcard tesseract?

Tags: ocr

I want tesseract to convert all the files of a folder. I do not want to merge the files in any way as I am having trouble with programs like hocr2pdf and pdfbeads merging more than one file at a time.

I run  `tesseract *.tif * hocr`  and end up with the following

`read_params_file: parameter not found: II*`

Comment: If you have multiple tif files in a directory (lets say example1.tif, example2.tif, and example3.tif then your command gets expandeded by **the shell** to `tesseract example1.tif example2.tif example3.tif hocr`. This is done before tesseract gets to see any parameters.

Comment: Here is another working example that works on multiple scanned files (A&S)
from https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~cbm/aands/ Link: tar.gz archive
Bash
for i in *.jpg ; do tesseract -l eng $i $i pdf; done; Searchable except ... Particular instances of ".1.1" don't get found, whereas ".1.2" do? For instance
17.1.1 fails but 17.1.2 succeeds as does 18.1.1 Suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried this and it works

```
for i in *.tif ; do tesseract $i outtext;  done;
```

Make sure when you are in terminal and you change directory to the location of all the files

Comment: I actually wanted split html files that command just replaces the last page converted, wildcarding outtext doesn't work

Comment: Then add $i on end of outtext and they would be seperate files ie outtext$i

Comment: Many Thanks. for i in *.tif ; do tesseract $i $i hocr; done; was just what I was looking for :D

Comment: This will always overwrite your file. So you only get the results of the very last image. This is simply wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified Meer Borg's answer slightly.  Using that code, my output file only had input from the last file in the folder.

Using tesseract's `stdout` option with `>>` is a way to get all of the output appended to a single file:

```
for i in *.tif ; do tesseract $i stdout >> outtext;  done;
```